# putSerializable not working in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been finding ways to resolve on how to pass multiple values from one class to the other.

I recently found a way which is to use `putSerializable` to do it but has not been successful. I only been able to return the last longitude and latitude to the other class.

This is my array json string:

```
{"longitude":"101.9366229","latitude":"1.236459"},
{"longitude":"101.930041","latitude":"1.224119"}]
```

Below are my code to pass the values:

```
class Findfriends extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        final String TAG = "Findfriends.java";
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // here Check for success tag
            try {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", args[0]);
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        GET_FRIENDS, "POST", params);

                if (json != null) {
                    Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                    return json;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            if (json != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Borrower_AP.this, json.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        Longitude = c.getDouble("longitude");
                        Latitude = c.getDouble("latitude");
                        Log.e(TAG, "Longitude: " + Longitude
                                + ", Latitude: " + Latitude);
                        coordinates.setLongt(Longitude);
                        coordinates.setLat(Latitude);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
    public class Coordinates implements Serializable {

    private Double lat;
    private Double longt;

    public Double getLat () {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    public Double getLongt() {
        return longt;
    }
    public void setLongt(Double longt) {
        this.longt = longt;
    }

}
```

Get the values back:

```
Intent intent=this.getIntent();
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

    Coordinates coordinates=(Coordinates)bundle.getSerializable("coordinates");
    System.out.println("Lat：" + coordinates.getLat());
    System.out.println("Long：" + coordinates.getLongt());
```

Comment: yes as per your code you only passing last item because Coordinates coordinates is a single object not any array of object are you getting me

Comment: @Pavan Can u write out an sample code? It would be clearer

Comment: see my updated answer any query u can ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your requirement you need Arraylist of your class Coordinates just add objects to it in loop where you parsing json and just send it to another activity and in new activity get it by casting it to Coordinates arraylist
here is the sample

if i consider coordinates in onpost method is arraylist

```
  ArrayList<Coordinates> coordinates=new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
```

in your onpost forloop

use following

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        Longitude = c.getDouble("longitude");
                        Latitude = c.getDouble("latitude");
                        Log.e(TAG, "Longitude: " + Longitude
                                + ", Latitude: " + Latitude);
                      Coordinates  coordinatesobj=new Coordinates();
                        coordinatesobj.setLongt(Longitude);
                        coordinatesobj.setLat(Latitude);
                         coordinates.add(coordinatesobj);
                    }
```

where you starting new activity there put below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("key", coordinates);
```

at receiving side activity

```
Intent intent=this.getIntent();
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

     ArrayList<Coordinates> coordinates=( ArrayList<Coordinates>)bundle.getSerializable("key");
```

hope it helps

Comment: Ok then how do i extracted latitude and longitude by pairs then?

Comment: by looping on Arraylist you will get object for ex. coordinates.get(0) will return you 1st position object

Comment: @QingYong if it helped you then you can accept this answer